# Does my proof prove the proposition?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to get better at proving. When it comes to it, I have done some in my multivariable analysis class (I didn't take single variable analysis) and some in logic during my Data modelling and databases and Intro to logic courses. My problems are that I don't really know how to format the proof so that it mathematically makes sense and when to know if a proof is correct.

I started going through the Intro to Metric Spaces and Topology textbook by Sutherland. The proof in question has to show that $ (X \setminus C) \cap D = D \setminus C $ where $ D \subseteq X $ and $ C \subseteq X $.

My proof is (where $ c \in C$ and $ d \in D$):

If $ D \subseteq X $ and $ C \subseteq X$, then $ (X \setminus C) \implies c\notin X$ and hence $ c\notin D $. Finally $ (X \setminus C) \supseteq (D \setminus C) $ then $ (X \setminus C) \cap D = D \setminus C $.

The proof in the textbook uses arbitrary points as in "Let $ x \in (X \setminus C) \cap D $ ...", which is something I commonly see. Is this for a specific reason? Is the use of $ \implies $ in my proof appropiate? How do I know when something doesn't need to be expanded further?

I appreciate any feedback for anything.

Comment: The usual proof of a set equality $A=B$ is by double inclusion: $A \subseteq B$ **and** $B \subseteq A$. Thus, the above will run as: $(X \setminus C) \cap D \subseteq D \setminus∖C$ and $D \setminus C \subseteq (X \setminus C) \cap D$.

Comment: The set inlusion $A \subseteq B$ will be proved: let $x \in A$ whatever and show that $x \in B$. Due to the fact that $x$ is whatever, the result holds **for every** $x$.

Comment: So, the "Let x∈(X∖C)∩D  ..." means: consider an $x$ in it that means that $x \in D$ **and** $x \in (X \setminus C)$. But $D \subseteq X$ and thus $x \in D$ implies $x \in X$ and with $x \in (X \setminus C)$ we have $x \notin C$. Thus, we have $x \in D$ **and**  $x \notin C$.

Comment: The ",,, then (X∖C)⟹c∉X" is wrong: $(X \setminus C)$ is a *set* and thus cannot "imply" a statement $C \notin X$. You have assumed $c \in C$; but $C \subseteq X$ and thus $c \in X$ also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The proof in the textbook uses arbitrary points as in "Let ∈(∖)∩
> ...", which is something I commonly see. Is this for a specific reason?

Yes this is for a specific reason. To prove equality of $(X\setminus C)\cap D$ and $D\setminus C$, we have to prove the two inclusions $(X\setminus C)\cap D\subseteq D\setminus C$ and $(X\setminus C)\cap D\supseteq D\setminus C$.

Now say we want to prove $(X\setminus C)\cap D\subseteq D\setminus C$. That is to say, all elements of $(X\setminus C)\cap D\subseteq D\setminus C$ are also elements of $D\setminus C$, or said more formally, $\forall x\in (X\setminus C)\cap D,\ x\in D\setminus C$.

If we look at this formal statement, it says we have to prove something for *all* $x$ in some set. To prove such a statement, you usually start with "Let $x\in (X\setminus C)\cap D$" and end with "So $x\in D\setminus C$". Because then $x$ is arbitrary, so you have indeed proven it for *all* $x$.

For example, we can say "Let $x\in (X\setminus C)\cap D$, then per definition of $\cap$ we have $x\in D$ and $x\in X\setminus C$. From definition of setminus, $x\in X\setminus C$ gives that $x\in X$ and $x\notin C$. So we have $x\in D$ and $x\in X$ and $x\notin C$. So in particular, $x\in D$ and $x\notin C$. Per definition of setminus, it then follows that $x\in D\setminus C$.", which is a very complete and verbose proof.

If some one comes along and asks "But I have this element $y\in (X\setminus C)\cap D$, does it also work for that element?", you can say "Yes! Because per definition of $\cap$ we have $y\in D$ and ......, it then follows that $y\in D\setminus C$". You indeed see this way of writing proofs makes it work for every element.

> How do I know when something doesn't need to be expanded further?

This is usually the most difficult part of writing a proof (If the proof itself isn't). In general, it need not be expanded further if you have tied everything to theorems/axioms in the relevant material, or if you can confidently assume that the reader can fill in the details themself. So this depends heavily on where your proof will end up: If it is a homework assignment for an introductory course, you should ideally assume no prior knowledge on the subject, and expand on everything, referencing the relevant axioms and statements in the book. If it is for an advanced course, you can omit the details with "We know from our previous course that ..." or something (preferably with references to the material in the previous course, if the result is not "standard"). If it is in a mathematical paper, you can assume that the reader can fill in quite a lot of details.

P.S. A general tip: You can just use words in a proof. Please do not try too much to put everything into symbols; Only use symbols if they are clearer to the reader (and yourself) than words. E.g. $(X\setminus C)\cap D$ is quite difficult to put in words, but $\forall$ and $\in$ are usually equally valid as words as symbols. So in my opinion, both "For all $x$ in $(X\setminus C)\cap D$ we have that $x$ is an element of $D\setminus C$" and "$\forall x\in(X\setminus C)\cap D,\ x\in D\setminus C$" are equally clear.

Comment: As I've read, to prove set equality it is typically done by double inclusion. I assume there are other methods to prove set equality, no? Does we always have to stick to double inclusion? Or is it just preferred because of its simplicity? Are proofs always preferred to be as simple as possible (as much as it allows)? I appreciate your answer, really clear!

Comment: "Does we always have to stick to double inclusion?" - The short answer is yes. How you prove double inclusion, and whether you do it yourself or use some theorem (where in the proof of the theorem, they must have done that), or prove some slightly-different-wording-but-essentialy-the-same-thing, is dependent on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

The $\Rightarrow$ refers to a logical implication, it is used as $P\Rightarrow Q$ where $P$ and $Q$ are propositions, meaning that if $P$ is true then so is $Q$. You wrote $(X\setminus C)\Rightarrow c\notin X$ which makes no sense as $X\setminus C$ is a set, this is not a proposition. It is asked to show that some set is equal to another set, usually we do this by proving the two inclusions $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$. Let's show that $(X\setminus C)\cap D\subseteq D\setminus C$. Let $x\in (X\setminus C)\cap D$, the goal is to show that $x\in D\setminus C$, we already know that $x\in D$ since $(X\setminus C)\cap D\subseteq D$, and since $x\in X\setminus C$ we also know that $x\notin C$ so that $x\in D\setminus C$. On the other hand, suppose now $x\in D\setminus C$ then since $D\setminus C\subseteq D$ we also have $x\in D$. We also know that $x\in D\setminus C$ so $x\notin C$ and therefore $x\in X\setminus C$ so $x\in (X\setminus C)\cap D$.

You could also prove the double inclusion without the "let $x\in\cdots$" because this one is fairly easy, draw some patatoids to see why.

Comment: Is it always the case that you need to proof set equality using double inclusion? Or is it used because it is the simplest? I appreciate your answer!

Comment: To prove that two sets $A$ and $B$ are equal you have to prove that $\forall x,(x\in A)\iff (x\in B)$, this can be done by equivalence. In general you won't be able to do so, this works only for very simple examples and the two-inclusions methods is by far the most used, it is as simple as it is effective. You can sometimes exhibit another set $C$ and show with different arguments and usually by double-inclusion that $A=C$ and $B=C$ so that $A=B$, but this is used when the given sets are not handy so you have to split the hard work to make it intelligible.